# NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

When I connected a single node cassandra it is working fine. Where as I connected a three node cluster (10.20.12.20, 10.20.12.21, 10.20.12.22) it is throwing below error. Why it is trying to connect localhost ?

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042] Cannot connect), localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:232) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1619) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1537) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.4.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you maybe share your code and configuration? It would help to spot any possible issue.

Comment: CONFIGURATION # Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=guru_keyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=10.202.82.25,10.180.19.57,10.180.12.22
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.username=cassandra

Comment: CODE https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-cassandra-example

Comment: Its working fine with standalone cluster but not with above three node cluster...not sure what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/CassandraClusterFactoryBean.html#DEFAULT_CONTACT_POINTS) (in case of any error or missing property) it will try to connect to localhost, as that is set as `DEFAULT_CONTACT_POINTS`

Your syntax is correct, my guess would be that the property is not read by your application at all. You can try to debug it and verify.

As for debug: the contactpoints are set [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/f3115017d4a04e105d4046f6fd716ac308ecd7aa/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/AbstractClusterConfiguration.java#L88), if you check it will always set to [default=localhost](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/f3115017d4a04e105d4046f6fd716ac308ecd7aa/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/AbstractClusterConfiguration.java#L170).

In your CassandraConfig beside overriding the `getKeyspaceName()` method, you also need to Override the `cluster()` and `cassandraMapping()` methods to make it work with your desired setup. E.g:

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    public static final String KEYSPACE = "my_keyspace";
    // read contact points from config
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;


    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean bean = super.cluster();
        bean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        return bean;
    }
```

*Also a side note:* you will get the expected behaviour, if you only add one contact-point, as the driver will look-up all the available nodes. Actually in case if you want to restrict communication with a specific node, you need to implement `loadBalancingPolicy` for exlusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply , but I am deleting records so it would fallow write consistence check there it would fail if I use one node. Have you used Apache Cassandra Opensource driver ?

Comment: Please tell me how to debug the Repository , not able to get where it being initialized the connection in spring-data-cassandra ?

Comment: I updated my answer as it was too long to fit in the comment.

Comment: Thank you so much , what you said correct , it is not reading/loading application.properties i.e. contact points.. how to to load it , by default spring boot loads it right ?

Comment: In your example you need to update your CassandraConfig class to use the property instead of the hard-coded default value. Please, see example code in my updated answer.